# JQuery Ajax Basic Authentication Header doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, http, basic-authentication

I am trying to make a simple GET request on a Server in JQuery.

```
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("hello" + ":" + "world")
        },
        url: "http://hello.world?Id=1",
        method: "GET",
        success: function () {
        },
    }).then(function () {
    });
```

The Problem is that when the Request gets sent, the Authentication Header is not put into the request correctly:

```
Host: hello.world
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Comment: You're probably showing us the request headers for a preflight OPTIONS request instead of a GET request. Is that right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When sending an HTTP request to another origin, the request can be either "simple" or "non-simple". A request becomes non-simple if it uses either (or both)

- An HTTP verb other than HEAD, GET, or POST; or,
- A request header other than `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Language`, or `Content-Type`

Since your request sets the `Authorization` header, it is non-simple.

When a request is non-simple, the browser first sends a *preflight* request using the OPTIONS method. That's the request you're seeing in your question. (See [HTML5 Rocks on preflight requests](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-handling-a-not-so-simple-request) and [my answer on [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/710446)). The preflight doesn't include the non-simple headers, but lists them in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header.

If the server responds to the preflight correctly, the browser will *then* issue the real request. In this case, the browser is looking for the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` from the server to indicate that the non-simple `Authorization` header is okay to send in the actual request. Your server must include that header in its response.

Comment: Thanks, So the Problem basically lies with the server?

Comment: @Bajellor Yes; if you need to send a a cross-origin request that includes the `Authorization` header, the server must (1) support CORS and (2) explicitly allow the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Does the server need to implement a OPTIONS method in which it somehow checks if the authorization is allowed or something?

Comment: The server must handle preflight requests sent with an OPTIONS method. The only thing the server needs to do during a preflight is (1) check `Access-Control-Request-Method` and include it in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` if it doesn't have a problem with that method and (2) check `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and include them in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` if it doesn't have a problem with any of the headers. Please read the linked articles and let me know if anything is still unclear. (Mine is shorter (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/710446), but HTML5 Rocks is more thorough.)